# WPF - getting and retrieving children

Tags: wpf

I have a component with several children, for example, a Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Button></Button>
    <Button></Button>
</Grid>
<Grid>
</Grid>
```

I need to get all the children of this component (in this example, the two buttons) in a variable, delete them of his father (the Grid) and insert them as children of another component, for example, the last empty Grid. How can I do this? Important: the children may be anything (buttons, grids, textboxes, etc).

Comment: One more thing: the children may contain childs, that must be transferred to the other father with the same extructure.

Comment: I've tried:

    private void myGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {    
        Grid newGrid = new Grid();

        UIElement child = (UIElement)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, 0);

        this.Children.Clear();

        newGrid.Children.Add(child);
        this.Children.Add(newGrid);
    }

In fact, I'm trying to create a new Grid that wraps the content of the original Grid.

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting code in a comment. That's just not readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (Grid1.Children.Count > 0)
{
  var element = Grid1.Children[0];
  Grid1.Children.Remove(element);
  Grid2.Children.Add(element);
}
```

If you need to consider other containers than `Grid` (`Decorator`, `ContentControl`, `ContentPresenter`), you'll have to adapt the logic to each case (`Child` or `Content` property instead of `Children`).

Comment: Not necessarily only Grid, but all Panel-derived container elements.